# Storing a SketchUp file in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, sketchup

I am sorry if this is a relatively dumb question, but I was wondering if there is a way to store a SketchUp file (.skp) in a PostGIS database?  I was thinking about as a blob, but I wasn't sure if anyone has had success with this.  The record would be a point location.  Right now I am doing a file path link to the file on the directory, but I was hoping there was a way to store the file in the database.  I would like to use this for data storage, but also as a means to retreive and view the data as well.

Thanks...

Comment: Do you want to save file or its content into database. If you want save file then blob or bytea are solutions for it. If you want to save data then collada2pgsql might be solution. You see the difference ?

Comment: I do see the difference.  I was wondering if there has been successful examples of this.  we may want to do both, so the collada2pgsql is really godo to know.  Thanks.

Comment: collada2pgsql can not be find anywhere, do you hava it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Collada (COLLAborative Design Asset) is a 3D format which was initially developed by Sony**

can be imported to PostGIS as a 3D entities

```
USAGE : collada2pgsql [options] colladafile [schema.]table

OPTIONS :
-s
Set the SRID field. If not specified it defaults to -1.
-d
Drops the table, then recreates it with current collada file data.
-c
Appends shape file into current table, must be exactly the same table schema.
!!! : The options -d and -a are mutually exclusive.
-g
Specify the name of the geometry column (mostly useful in append mode).
-t
Import collada file data with informations about textures.
-dir
Specify the directory where the textures will be stored.
default: '/tmp/textures'
-I
Create a GiST index on the geometry column.
-?
Display this help screen.
```

Source:
http://postgisand3d.blogspot.com/2008/06/collada-import.html

Comment: Do you know where to download the collada2psql tool?

Comment: the collada2psql  is out of date?